# Parameter estimate interpretations in lm with offset

Tags: r, offset, lme4-nlme

I want to analyze flight times of an insect (in function of several weather parameters), but these are done at different distances.

One option could be to calculate the speed and analyze this, or what my professor proposed is to use flight time and then **distance as an offset**. (It's also in a mixed model with Individual as random factor)

My model looks like this:

```r
lmer(Flighttime ~ Temperature + (1|IndividualID), 
    offset=Distance, na.action=na.omit, data=KMIdata)
```

Can someone help me to interpret the outcome?

I have parameter estimates between 300 and 600, but my flight time only reach between 0 and 8 minutes maximum.
Should I divide them by something?
Can someone explain explain offset in a normal linear regression?
I can only find videos with count data and Poisson regression but this is not the case for my data.

Comment: An offset is literally just a thing you "add" to the right side of the equation. This is a difference when you are fitting a linear model on the original scale. But I wonder if you don't mean to fit a log transformed model so that "distance" is like a denominator, that is flighttime/distance is measured in speed units.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr** you should probably just compute speed and use it as your response variable; you can do this on the fly in the formula, i.e. `Flighttime/Distance ~ Temperature + ...`

Following up on @AdamO's comment,this sounds like it might be a miscommunication between you and your advisor; you probably want to use a *multiplicative* offset, or (more easily) just use a ratio of (flight time/distance) as your response variable.

I'll start by explaining what your *current* model does. I'm going to leave out the random effects, since they're not relevant to the particular question. I'm also going to include the offset term in the formula itself; this is equivalent but I find it slightly easier to understand.

```r
Flighttime ~ Temperature + offset(Distance)
```

This fits the model

$$
F = \beta_0 + \beta_T \textrm{Temperature} + \textrm{Distance} + \epsilon
$$

(where $\epsilon$ is a residual Gaussian error term). The first clue that this doesn't make sense it that the **units don't match**. If flight time is measured in minutes and distance in meters, then we have different units on each side. (The units of $\beta_0$ would normally match the units of the response [time in this case], the units of $\beta_T$ would be (time/temperature) so that the units of $\beta_T \textrm{Temperature}$ would be [time], and would match the response.

Forgetting about the (probably incorrect) offset term for the moment, the meaning of the parameters you're getting in the range from 300-600 is (assuming that these are the units for $\beta_T$) that a 1 °C change (assuming that you're measuring temperature in °C) would lead to an expected change in flight time of 300-600 minutes. Either your insects are very sensitive to temperature, or something is messed up (if you post some plots of your data or at least the results of `summary(fitted_model)` we might be able to say more ...).

You could fit a multiplicative offset by using a *logarithmic link* model:

```r
glmer(Flighttime ~ Temperature + (1|IndividualID) + offset(log(Distance)), 
    data=KMIdata, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
```

This is fitting the model $F = \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_T T + \log D + \epsilon)$, which if you do the algebra (separate out $\exp(\log D) = D$ from the $\exp()$ term and divide both sides by $D$) is equivalent to $F/D = \exp(\beta_0 + \beta_T T + \epsilon)$. This assumes an *exponential* relationship between flight time (scaled by distance) and temperature, and a log-Normal rather than a Normal response distribution, but this could very well be reasonable for your situation.

People don't usually use offsets for models like this (i.e., continuous responses/linear models) because there's nothing stop you from fitting $F/D = \beta_0 + \beta_T$ directly. This doesn't work right for Poisson models used for count data (you can only fit a Poisson model to discrete counts, not to ratios), which is why people use offsets in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much! This clarifies a lot. I will probably analyse it just as speed instead to make interpretations easier.

Comment: However, how should I interpret then the parameter estimates of this glmer with the link=log?

Comment: If you fit with a log link it's probably easiest to look at descriptions of "how to interpret parameters in a Poisson regression", as these almost always use the log link ($\beta$ = expected effect of a 1-unit increase on log(response), or $\exp(\beta)$ = expected multiplicative effect from a 1-unit increase, or $\beta \approx$ proportional change if $\beta$ is small)